# How to filter the existing month into next month?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT pegawai.Nama, pegawai.Tempat_Lahir, pegawai.Tanggal_lahir,
       pegawai.NIP, pegawai.Tingkat_Ijasah, pegawai.Jurusan,
       pegawai.Golongan_CPNS, pegawai.TMT_CPNS, pegawai.Alamat,
       pensiun.TMT_Pensiun, pensiun.SKPensiun 
from pegawai
    JOIN pensiun on pegawai.NIP = pensiun.NIP) 
WHERE (MONTH(CONVERT(Date, Month)) = MONTH(GETDATE()) + 1)) AS pensiun.TMT_Pensiun
```

Months in the filter is `TMT_Pensiun`.

Comment: Please tag your questions appropriately. This has nothing to do with Javascript, PHP or jQuery.

Comment: can you explain what you are expecting.?

Comment: Some syntax errors there...

Comment: #1: You can't alias a condition in WHERE. #2: Your logic will fall in December

Comment: I Want to keep the existing date in the filter to the next month

Comment: I have a date : 02/11/2016

in the filter becomes : 02/12/2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even your problem is not much clear but as per my understanding with your problem you can try below query-

```
SELECT pegawai.Nama, pegawai.Tempat_Lahir, pegawai.Tanggal_lahir,
       pegawai.NIP, pegawai.Tingkat_Ijasah, pegawai.Jurusan,
       pegawai.Golongan_CPNS, pegawai.TMT_CPNS, pegawai.Alamat,
       pensiun.TMT_Pensiun, pensiun.SKPensiun 
FROM pegawai
    JOIN pensiun ON pegawai.NIP = pensiun.NIP 
WHERE MONTH(pensiun.TMT_Pensiun) = MONTH(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT pegawai.Nama, pegawai.Tempat_Lahir, pegawai.Tanggal_lahir,
       pegawai.NIP, pegawai.Tingkat_Ijasah, pegawai.Jurusan,
       pegawai.Golongan_CPNS, pegawai.TMT_CPNS, pegawai.Alamat,
       pensiun.TMT_Pensiun, pensiun.SKPensiun 
from pegawai JOIN pensiun 
on pegawai.NIP = pensiun.NIP
WHERE (MONTH(pensiun.TMT_Pensiun) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```